# How would I plot the inequality lines together with the intersection plot of the inequalities?

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, geometry, inequalities

For example, I've got the following code:

```
Plot[{x >= 5, y >= 8, x + 2y <= 64, x + y <= 40}]
```

This would plot:

[image]

Now, this is fair enough. It shows me the graphical solution of my four inequalities, however, I also would like to have the lines of those inequalities to be plot as well alongside the graphical solution of my inequalities. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amplifying on Bill's answer

```
Legended[
 Show[
  RegionPlot[
   x >= 5 && y >= 8 && x + 2 y <= 64 && x + y <= 40, {x, 0, 40}, {y, 
    0, 35},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
   PlotPoints -> 100],
  ContourPlot[
   Evaluate[
    Tooltip /@ {x == 5, y == 8, x + 2 y == 64, x + y == 40}],
   {x, 0, 40}, {y, 0, 35}],
  PlotLabel -> Style[
    x >= 5 && y >= 8 && x + 2 y <= 64 && x + y <= 40,
    14, Bold]],
 Placed[
  LineLegend[
   ColorData[97] /@ Range[4],
   {x == 5, y == 8, x + 2 y == 64, x + y == 40}],
  {0.75, 0.75}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just a slightly compact way of Bob Hanlon's answer (which I voted for). Note [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) frames and uses [`Tooltip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html).  The aesthetics and control of [`Legended`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html) may be preferred.

```
cons = {x >= 5, y >= 8, x + 2 y <= 64, x + y <= 40};
eq = cons /. {(a_ >= b_) :> (a == b), a_ <= b_ :> a == b};
Show[RegionPlot[lab = Fold[And[#1, #2] &, cons], {x, 0, 35}, {y, 0, 35},
  PlotLabel -> Style[lab, Bold]], 
 ContourPlot[Evaluate[eq], {x, 0, 35}, {y, 0, 35}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Show[
  ...yourexistingplot...,
  ContourPlot[{x == 5, y == 8, x + 2y == 64, x + y == 40},{x,5,35},{y,5,30}]
]
```

which should overlay your two plots and show you your colored lines along the edges.

You can adjust the PlotRange option as needed to frame the plots.